# When i add data to firebase it updates the old data instead of writing new data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
private fun addToFavs() {
    val myFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    val newData=myFirebaseRef!!.child(AppConstants.FirebaseNodes.userNode).child(auth.currentUser!!.uid).child("fav").child(
        business.id).child("id").push()
   newData.setValue(business.id)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Void?> ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG, "added to fav")
            } else {

                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting data", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error " + task.exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }


}
```

```
{
    "TTmr8YNOaIQ6ZlJlHw2sONOLCz72": {
        "email": "arfaatqureshi232@hotmail.com",
        "fcmToken": "fv-otj0pR6OnSUNY2buZtb:APA91bGEBV80jo-SnJBHfJ6MxSXj0gLfvV9BKxX2SOmHstvLbUpRB0oxmSWRsfRsCJEnJ-D77UTbhRIFv8cUQEozA68_wOeYm5es7klErvfi96Huez7KWsK5FrBfAmf2J-9ZqNhGvV5a",
        "followingStores": {
            "oGURUwXDgmgiXggcrnRAcNj0AMs1": {
                "id": "oGURUwXDgmgiXggcrnRAcNj0AMs1"
            }
        },
        "id": "TTmr8YNOaIQ6ZlJlHw2sONOLCz72",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lat": 0,
        "lng": 5,
        "mobileNo": "034396524876",
        "name": "a.qureshi",
        "online": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your database structure? You are using `push()` method which creates a new node.

Comment: When using a call to `.push()` a new random key is always generated. Can you please show us how this method behaves differently? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: i have tried .push() too.  but instead of adding new data it replaces the old data with new one. @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo the structure inside the user is like fav(Node)->ID(Node)-> name:value
it works good for the first time . but after the first time it keep on replacing the old data with the new one.

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: But how can i add a file here?

Comment: You can copy the contents of your JSON file and paste them in your question.

Comment: Please check now .

Comment: `.child("fav")` I can't see any node named fav in your JSON

Comment: its not added yet. it has the same structure as "followingstores"